# Conjuction of filters in stream

Tags: java

It streams a list and runs concjuction for all elements of `List<Predicate>`:

```
// ...
private List<Predicate> filters = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
    .stream()
    .filter(p -> {
            for(Predicate filter : filters) {
                if ( !filter.test(p)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        })
// ...
```

How to write it in Java 8 style the filter part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `Stream` over the `List` of `Predicate`s and use `allMatch` to require that the element of the outer `Stream` matches all the `Predicate`s.

```
.stream()
.filter(p -> filters.stream().allMatch(filter -> filter.test(p)))
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Stream::allMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) which performs exactly what you wish to accomplish. It returns `true` only if all predicates in stream (`filters` in your question) return true.

```java
private List<Predicate> filters = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
    .stream()
    .filter(p -> filters.stream().allMatch(filter -> filter.test(p))
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you could combine your predicates into one by reducing them. Later you can use this predicate to filter by it :

```
Predicate<?> combinedPredicate = filters.stream().reduce(Predicate::and).orElse(e -> true);
//or 
Predicate<?> combinedPredicate = filters.stream().reduce(e -> true, Predicate::and);
...
stream()
.filter(combinedPredicate)
...
```